# Changing MAC address using crontabs

Tags: bash, macos, shell, networking, cron

I made a small bash script that randomizes my MAC address on OS X. It works well, when executed directly. I also added this script as a sudo crontab, and changing the MAC address and displaying a notification using Apple Script does not work. Am I missing something?

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
if ping -c 2 google.com
    then
        exit
    else
        RANGE=255
        rangen() {
                NUM=$RANDOM
                let "NUM %= $RANGE"
                OCT=$(echo "obase=16;$NUM" | bc)
                if [ ${#OCT} == 1 ]; then
                    OCT='0'$OCT
                fi
                echo $OCT
        }

        A=$(rangen); B=$(rangen); C=$(rangen); D=$(rangen); E=$(rangen); F=$(rangen)
        mac="${A}:${B}:${C}:${D}:${E}:${F}"
        ifconfig en0 ether $mac
        ifconfig en0 down
        ifconfig en0 up
        osascript -e 'display notification "New address." with title "MAC Script"'
        open -a safari https://captive.apple.com/hotspot.detet.html
        exit
fi
```

Comment: You don't seem to be taking into account the flags in the OUI. You need to make sure that the U/L bit is set, and the I/G bit is not.

Comment: I don’t think that this is the problem, when I execute the script directly from a cli, it works like a charm.

Comment: No, I wasn't equating that to your problem, but it can certainly cause other problems.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the tipp!